# How to check if dll generated is statically or dynamically linked?

Tags: windows, dll, makefile, static-linking, dynamic-linking

Following is my linking command:

```
Running Mkbootstrap for XML::SAX::ExpatXS ()
    C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe -MExtUtils::Command -e chmod -- 644 ExpatXS.bs

link -out:blib\arch\auto\XML\SAX\ExpatXS\ExpatXS.dll -dll -nologo -nodefaultlib -debug -opt:ref,icf  -libpath:"C:\Perl\lib\CORE"  -machine:x86 ExpatXS.obj -def:ExpatXS.def
Creating library blib\arch\auto\XML\SAX\ExpatXS\ExpatXS.lib and object blib\arch\auto\XML\SAX\ExpatXS\ExpatXS.exp
```

The compilation flags used are `/Zi /GF /MD -c`

I want to know if this dll is getting statically or dynamically linked. I referred http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3.aspx but the compiler ignores these options when I specify them in my makefile.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your snippet only shows the DLL getting built, it doesn't say anything about the program that uses the DLL. Which has the choice to use the DLL either way.

If you have no idea then a simple way to find out is to run `Dumpbin.exe /imports` on the EXE. You'll see the exports from the DLL that are actually used listed in the output. If you don't see anything then the DLL could only be dynamically loaded.  Or not at all.  The debugger shows notifications for DLLs that get loaded into a process, you'll see them in the Output window.

Answer (score 2):

Download a copy of the windows [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/), fire it up and load your freshly minted dll.

It will show all the DLLs that your dll imports. If one of the imports has a name like `msvcr<blah>.dll` (e.g., `msvcrt.dll`, or `msvcr90.dll` — you get the picture), then it is using the c-runtime in a dll (which incidentally, is the recommended thing for a dll to do).